# Calling web-services internally within the server

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a web-service getEmployee() which gets the employee detais for a single employee, when an id is passed.

Another web-service on the same server getEmployeeList() which gets the whole list of employees, when a department is passed. This gets the id's for the departments and then calls the getEmployee() service to get all the details.

The response of the web-service getEmployeeList() is basically a collection of the responses of getEmployee().

My question here is how best to implement it? Is it better to call getEmployee() multiple times from getEmployeeList() internally, or to just call the process method of getEmployee() each time ( there is a process method in getEmployee() which takes as input an xml and returns the response xml)

Comment: How is the overall set of employee data stored? You mention xml files for the individual employees. Are they separate xml files? Is it xml data in a database? Is it one big xml file that you look for a specific element in getEmployee() to parse?

Comment: @Chill it is stored in the database. the xml file is just the input to the web-service, passing in the id. It has to query the db, get the details, and build a response xml with the details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact answer is going to depend on the internals of your application is structured, but generally I would **not** invoke another web service API running on the same server in order to service a request.  That's going to be inefficient and ties one implementation to another.

If you need to return a list of employees, your front-end REST layer should invoke a method from the business or middle layer to retrieve the relevant information, usually in the form of a set of domain objects.  This middle layer would be responsible for getting the actual data from a persistence layer or some sort - i.e. getting the proper list of employees from a database of some sort, though that exact implementation detail should not be relevant.

These can then be converted into the proper format for building the response to the client - i.e. JAXB objects for XML.  (Your middle layer could also directly return these JAXB objects, but there are pros/cons of this approach)

Answer (score 1):

If there are functionalities that can be reused in multiple web services, then that functionality is a good candidate for being separate functions that can be called by another function, as opposed to just having that functionality *living inside the endpoint code* itself

when I come to the point that those types of functions need to be created, the question usually becomes a question of whether or not it is a `model` functionality or a `helper` functionality.

At the end of the day, if you were to make a curl request from an API to another endpoint within that same API, you're just using up unnecessary time fussing with network bandwidth... which often ends up being  a local-to-local scenario, but sometimes isn't, in which case you'd instantly notice how it wasn't a good idea.