# making multiple REST calls from Java internally

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I have to get list of users using our product. The current design of my company's db works like this:

1. query the db for getting groups of users who use a specific product
2. get the group id from there
3. query on the group id to get list of users

I have REST api for both already written long back by some other team folks. I thought of making multiple REST calls from out front end(angular) but I was told that it will be time consuming and inefficient.

I heard that I can make other REST calls form Java itself and just return the final result - list of users. Is this solution viable?  (I have also read articles here on stack overflow that this not a good idea: [Calling web-services internally within the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640919/calling-web-services-internally-within-the-server)) but I would need a good reason to argue (at least) and choose the best of the two approaches.

Note: I am not supposed to write new queries and/or change the existing once. (which is a big problem.. but I cant help it)

Comment: Is the REST API external to the application? If so, it's perfectly fine to call out to an external service. If the REST API is wrapping around classes within the app, then why not access the internal API directly? You don't need to marshall data across HTTP when you can access within the same JVM application. Regarding the query, it would be more efficient to perform a single aggregate query (with GROUP BY) than to try to piece together the data with multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to my mind it just sounds really inefficient. The REST API is supposed to be the interface between frontend and backend. I don't think it makes much sense to use this interface in this situation. Your business logic should offer you the possibility to access the data programmatically anyway.

Just think: If you make a REST request you have to create / open a socket, wrap the request into text (xml / json), parse it on the other side, create a response, wrap that into text and parse it again. A library call in java is a *lot* more efficient because there is virtually no overhead.

I would recommend to extend the REST API to be able to retrieve the information from the client side (using javascript) with a single call.

Comment: Well, REST is fine for backend/backend communication, too :) Apart from that, I fully hook up with you.